# Fastest Way to become a US Citizen

Tags: united-states, immigration, citizenship, visa

Fastest Way to become a US Citizen →

In general, getting a US citizenship is a tedious process it takes a lot of time.

If someone starts a Business in the USA after coming from India and gives employment to Americans can such a person avail his citizenship in very few years?

Can some knowledgeable person help me regarding this?

Comment: You'll generally have to go through the green card process first. I think you're thinking of an [EB-5 visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-fifth-preference-eb-5/about-eb-5-visa-classification) which would give you a green card immediately but you have to invest between 500k and 1million up front.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that one cannot start a business in the USA in most circumstances without first having an appropriate visa.

Comment: This question should be on [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question that was asked, although I suspect that the real question might be "what is the fastest way to get a visa that ultimately makes me eligible to become a U.S. citizen?"

In general, the way that one becomes a naturalized citizen is by first obtaining a visa that allows permanent residence in the United States by any of multiple available methods, then spending at least five years in that status, and then making an application for U.S. citizenship, which is granted as a matter of course if you pass a citizenship test, an English language fluency test, and a moderately thorough background check.

This five year waiting period is reduced to three years for someone who has a permanent resident visa because he or she is the spouse of a U.S. citizen (incidentally, being the spouse of a U.S. citizen is also one of the fastest ways to get a permanent resident visa).

Special rules also exist to grant citizenship, in the case of people who are seeking U.S. citizenship [based upon honorable service in the United States military](https://www.uscis.gov/military) and sometimes their families as well, and in the case of [minor children of people who become naturalized citizens](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-parents) of the United States. I suspect that neither of these options are viable ones in the circumstances discussed in the question.

See generally [here](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-naturalization).

Comment: You missed the *fastest* fastest way: have Congress pass a private bill granting you citizenship, which they can legally do even if you've never set foot in the US.

Comment: @cpast True enough, although at the rate at which legislative moves though Congress these days, it might be a close thing, in addition to being virtually impossible to accomplish in practice.

Comment: so after green card, one can file for citizenship after 5 Years.

Comment: @Champion Yes, unless you fall into one of the exceptions, the main one of which is for spouses where there is a three year rule.